# Code works in Java but not Android project

Tags: java, android

So I have some sensor data that I need to smooth in my app. When I test it, it doesn't work. It will fail by inserting wrong values in different places, skipping some and so forth. But when I run the code with the debugger, it does work as expected! I also tried copying it over to a Java project, and it seems to work just fine there aswell! It almost feels like there are some threads that are using the same variables or whatever, I don't know Android well enough. 
This is the Java code, it's the same for my Android project, except the print statements of course:

```
package com.company;

public class Main {
    private static final int SMOOTH_N = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
    }

    public Main(){
        int[][] x = testRawGestureData();

        System.out.println("Before normal");
        printData(x);
        x = normalizeData(x);
        System.out.println("After normal");
        printData(x);
    }

    /**
     * Using moving window to smooth the data by averaging.
     *
     * @param rawGestureData
     */
    private int[][] normalizeData(int[][] rawGestureData) {
        int[][] tmpArray = new int[22][6]; // Temporary array with two extra rows at the end to help with the smoothing.
        int[][] smoothedGestureData = new int[20][6];

        //Copies raw gesture data to tmpArray.
        for (int i = 0; i < rawGestureData.length; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(rawGestureData[i], 0, tmpArray[i], 0, rawGestureData[i].length);
        }

        //Adds 2 extra rows to the tmpArray.
        System.arraycopy(rawGestureData, 18, tmpArray, 20, smoothedGestureData.length - 18);

        //For each column...
        for (int col = 0; col < 6; col++) {
            int sum = 0;
            int modulusCounter = 1;
            int smoothedRowCounter = 0;

            //For each row...
            for (int row = 0; row < tmpArray.length; row++) {
                sum += tmpArray[row][col];
                System.out.println("rawVal: " + String.valueOf(tmpArray[row][col]));
                //For every third row...
                if (modulusCounter % SMOOTH_N == 0) {
                    int average = Math.round(sum / SMOOTH_N);
                    System.out.println("AVG: " + average);
                    smoothedGestureData[smoothedRowCounter++][col] = average;
                    sum = 0;
                    System.out.println("SMOOTHARRAY");
                    printData(smoothedGestureData);

                    if(row<21){ //Fixes the trouble at the end
                        row -= 2; //Reset the row one step back.
                    }

                    if(row == 13){
                        System.out.println("BREAK");
                    }
                    System.out.println("ROW: " + String.valueOf(row));
                }
                modulusCounter++;
            }
        }
        printData(smoothedGestureData);
        return smoothedGestureData;
    }

    private int[][] testRawGestureData() {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int[][] rawGestureData = new int[20][6];
        for (int i = 0; i < rawGestureData.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < rawGestureData[i].length; j++) {
                int nbr = i + j + 1;
                rawGestureData[i][j] = nbr;
            }
        }

        return rawGestureData;
    }

    //Print the gesture array.
    private void printData(int[][] rawGestureData) {
        for (int[] row : rawGestureData) {
            StringBuilder currentRow = new StringBuilder();
            for (int measurementData : row) {
                currentRow.append(String.valueOf(measurementData)).append(",");
            }
            System.out.println(currentRow);
        }
        System.out.println("Done printing array");
    }
}
```

This will give me the results:

```
Before normal
1,2,3,4,5,6,
2,3,4,5,6,7,
3,4,5,6,7,8,
4,5,6,7,8,9,
5,6,7,8,9,10,
6,7,8,9,10,11,
7,8,9,10,11,12,
8,9,10,11,12,13,
9,10,11,12,13,14,
10,11,12,13,14,15,
11,12,13,14,15,16,
12,13,14,15,16,17,
13,14,15,16,17,18,
14,15,16,17,18,19,
15,16,17,18,19,20,
16,17,18,19,20,21,
17,18,19,20,21,22,
18,19,20,21,22,23,
19,20,21,22,23,24,
20,21,22,23,24,25,
Done printing array

After normal
2,3,4,5,6,7,
3,4,5,6,7,8,
4,5,6,7,8,9,
5,6,7,8,9,10,
6,7,8,9,10,11,
7,8,9,10,11,12,
8,9,10,11,12,13,
9,10,11,12,13,14,
10,11,12,13,14,15,
11,12,13,14,15,16,
12,13,14,15,16,17,
13,14,15,16,17,18,
14,15,16,17,18,19,
15,16,17,18,19,20,
16,17,18,19,20,21,
17,18,19,20,21,22,
18,19,20,21,22,23,
19,20,21,22,23,24,
19,20,21,22,23,24,
19,20,21,22,23,24,
Done printing array
```

In android I get this:

```
    Before normal
    1,2,3,4,5,6,
    2,3,4,5,6,7,
    3,4,5,6,7,8,
    4,5,6,7,8,9,
    5,6,7,8,9,10,
    6,7,8,9,10,11,
    7,8,9,10,11,12,
    8,9,10,11,12,13,
    9,10,11,12,13,14,
    10,11,12,13,14,15,
    11,12,13,14,15,16,
    12,13,14,15,16,17,
    13,14,15,16,17,18,
    14,15,16,17,18,19,
    15,16,17,18,19,20,
    16,17,18,19,20,21,
    17,18,19,20,21,22,
    18,19,20,21,22,23,
    19,20,21,22,23,24,
    20,21,22,23,24,25,
    Done printing array

ataNormalizer: 13,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: Done printing array
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: ROW: 11
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 13
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 14
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 15
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: Ave 14
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: SmoothArray
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 2,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 3,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 4,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 5,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 6,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 7,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 8,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 9,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 10,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 11,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 12,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 13,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 14,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 0,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.366 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: Done printing array
12-27 22:56:24.367 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 3,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.368 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 18,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.369 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 2,3,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.370 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 7
12-27 22:56:24.371 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 12,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.372 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: Done printing array
12-27 22:56:24.372 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 12
12-27 22:56:24.373 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: SmoothArray
12-27 22:56:24.373 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 18,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.374 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 12,13,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.374 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 18,0,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.376 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 5
12-27 22:56:24.379 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: Ave 13
12-27 22:56:24.380 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 15,16,0,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.381 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: Done printing array
12-27 22:56:24.381 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: SmoothArray
12-27 22:56:24.382 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: SmoothArray
12-27 22:56:24.382 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 19
12-27 22:56:24.382 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: SmoothArray
12-27 22:56:24.382 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 16,17,18,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.383 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 19,20,21,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.383 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 7,8,9,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.383 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 8,9,10,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.383 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: ROW: 21
12-27 22:56:24.384 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 7,8,9,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.384 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 5
12-27 22:56:24.384 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 10,11,12,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.384 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 19,20,21,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.384 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 8,9,10,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.384 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 11,12,13,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.385 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 17,18,19,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.385 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 4,5,6,7,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.386 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 16,17,18,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.386 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 2,3,4,5,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.386 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 9,10,11,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.386 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 19,20,21,0,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.387 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 13
12-27 22:56:24.387 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: Ave 13
12-27 22:56:24.388 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 4,5,6,7,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.388 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 4,5,6,7,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.388 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 8,9,10,11,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.388 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 13,14,15,16,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.390 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 6,7,8,9,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.390 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 8,9,10,11,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.390 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 10,11,12,13,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.391 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 23
12-27 22:56:24.391 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 11,12,13,14,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.391 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 17,18,19,20,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.392 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 7
12-27 22:56:24.392 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: ROW: 1
12-27 22:56:24.392 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 7,8,9,10,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.392 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 9,10,11,12,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.393 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 12
12-27 22:56:24.396 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 19,20,21,22,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.396 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 14,15,16,17,18,0,
12-27 22:56:24.396 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 19,20,21,22,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.396 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 19
12-27 22:56:24.397 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 19,20,21,22,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.397 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: SmoothArray
12-27 22:56:24.397 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 14,15,16,17,18,0,
12-27 22:56:24.398 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 8,9,10,11,12,0,
12-27 22:56:24.398 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 19,20,21,22,0,0,
12-27 22:56:24.401 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 9,10,11,12,13,0,
12-27 22:56:24.402 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 12,13,14,15,16,0,
12-27 22:56:24.402 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: Ave 16
12-27 22:56:24.402 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 12,13,14,15,16,0,
12-27 22:56:24.404 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: ROW: 12
12-27 22:56:24.404 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: Ave 21
12-27 22:56:24.405 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: rawVal: 24
12-27 22:56:24.405 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 10,11,12,13,14,15,
12-27 22:56:24.405 23923-23923/com.project.iotap.iotap D/DataNormalizer: 12,13,14,15,16,17,
```

The thing that really irritates me is that it does work when running the app with the debugger, so it's difficult to debug.

Comment: how do you run your code in Android ? do you use main method ? if yes, I will say to you that is incorrect

Comment: Well, how to tell you, without *really irritating you*... **Android is not Java**!

Comment: In java, it is run from a callback that get's executed on another thread.